# i want to create generic variable which changes automatically with call to different factory calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to create generic variable which changes automatically with call to different factory calls.

currently i am using this:

```
IFactory1.query()
        .$promise
        .then(function onSuccess(typeContent) {
            //code
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            //code
        })

IFactory2.query()
        .$promise
        .then(function onSuccess(typeContent) {
            //code
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            //code
        })
.
.
.
IFactoryn.query()
        .$promise
        .then(function onSuccess(typeContent) {
            //code
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            //code
        })
```

i want a generic way to call different factories with a single line, something like this:

```
IFactory + number.query()
        .$promise
        .then(function onSuccess(typeContent) {
            //code
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            //code
        })
```

Comment: JavaScript != Java

Comment: i know...i am just thinking that any java user could help me too

Comment: This is not what tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a factory list and then use it:

```
var factoryList = [IFactory1, IFactory2, IFactory3];

var data = factoryList[number-1].query();
```